# How to show and hide a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a page in which when I click on a text then a `div` appears and when I click on the same text then the `div` disappears.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="description" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="faq-row">                      
        <a href="javascript:;" class="faq-row-handle">Business Friendly Environment</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 faq-row-content">                     
        <ul>
            <li>
                LR's spacious apartments provide ample room for work and play.
            </li>
            <li>
                Guests can access high speed internet and cable television from every room.
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>                     
    <div class="faq-row">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="faq-row-handle">Business Friendly Environment</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 faq-row-content">                       

        <ul>
            <li>
                LR's spacious apartments provide ample room for work and play.
            </li>
            <li>
                Guests can access high speed internet and cable television from every room.
            </li> 

        </ul>
    </div>                     
</div>
```

What I need is when I click on the first link then the first `div` appears and disappears ; and when I click on the second link then the second `div` appears and disappears.
At this point, when I click on a link, nothing happens.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".faq-row-handle").click(function(){
        $(".faq-row-content").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this)` instead of the class selector to target the `next()` element to `slideToggle()` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".faq-row-handle").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kjm5pe4m/2/)

Comment: thanx vincent..but it show text with content ..I need only text when i clicked on text then it need to show content ..please help me

Comment: you mean hide the text when you load the page and then show it on click ? Like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/kjm5pe4m/3/

Comment: Yes ..onpage load it need to hide when we click on the text then it need to show

Comment: Vincent ..when i provide the css to my text then it overlay ..please see the the link  ...https://jsfiddle.net/kjm5pe4m/4/

Comment: Because `a` is inline by default, you need to change it to `block` or `inline-block` to apply height on it. Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/kjm5pe4m/7/

Comment: you're welcome, mark this question as resolved if it helps you ;)